# View config getter callback for component `` must be a function

Tags: components, react-native, react-native-ios, simplemodal

I am working on my react native app, but when I try to use Modal component,this error shows up:

> View config getter callback for component `` must be a function

even if I just add `<Modal></Modal>` in my code and on Web stimulator it gives this error:

> InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document':
> The tag name provided ('') is not a valid name.

I am unable to solve this issue. Below is my complete code:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {Card,FAB,TextInput,Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import Modal from 'react-native';

const EmployeesInfo=()=> {

const [Name,setName]=useState("")
const [Email,setEmail]=useState("")
const [Phone,setPhone]=useState("")
const [Salary,setSalary]=useState("")
const [Pic,setPic]=useState("")
const [Modal,setModal]=useState("")

return (
  <View style={styles.root}>
  ...
  </View>
)}

export default EmployeesInfo

const theme ={colors:{primary:"red"}}

const styles= StyleSheet.create({

  root:{
    flex:1,
  },

  words:{
    margin:9
  }
})
```

Comment: If this didn't fixed your issue. Check out this answer too
[goto link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73042000/11819676)

Answer (score 3):

There is a very small error:
**You need to import a Component**

`import Modal from 'react-native';`

Change this to

`import { Modal } from 'react-native';`

And your code will be fine.